# How to Invoke solr DataImport Handler results in MVC Controller?

Tags: java, xml, asp.net-mvc, solr, solrnet

I'm a newbie to Solr.
I have done the following things.
i) Complete the installation of the Java Virtual Machine and Tomcat Apache for Solr.
ii) a) Configure the Schema.xml in the Following way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="productid" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="catalogitemno" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="string_value" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" /> 
    <field name="numeric_value" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="attributeid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="datatype" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" /> 


    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

</schema>
```

b) Configure the SolrConfig.xml and Include the DataImport in the following way.

```
    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">     
        <lst name="defaults">    
            <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>  
        </lst>   
   </requestHandler>

    <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:}/dih/" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

c) Configure the data-config.xml in the following way.

```
<span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">
    <dataConfig> 
      <script><![CDATA[
                function f1(row)        {
                var SplitString = row.get("string_value");
                if(SplitString!== null){
                var _SplitString = SplitString.split(',');
                row.put("string_value",_SplitString);
                }
                return row;
                }
        ]]>
      </script> 
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
        driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName;databaseName=ABCX;" 
        user="sa" 
        password="xxxxx" 
        batchSize="1" />  

        <document name="cd2">  
          <entity name="PAtt" transformer="script:f1" query="SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(  order by pro.productid asc) as 'id'
                                        ,pro.ProductID as 'productid'
                                        ,pro.CatalogItemNo as 'catalogitemno'
                                        ,pav.String_Value  as 'string_value'
                                        ,pav.Numeric_Value as 'numeric_value'
                                        ,pav.AttributeID as 'attributeid'
                                        ,pav.DataType as 'datatype'
                                        FROM [retail].[Product] pro inner join retail.ProductAttributesValues pav on pav.ProductID = pro.ProductID;">  

                <field column="id" name="id" />  
                <field column="productid" name="productid" />  
                <field column="catalogitemno" name="catalogitemno" />
                <field column="string_value" name="string_value" />
                <field column="numeric_value" name="numeric_value" />
                <field column="attributeid" name="attributeid" />
                <field column="datatype" name="datatype" />

            </entity>  

        </document>  
    </dataConfig>  
</span>
```

iii) Index was Created and i got the following result in the dataImport Query Window. For Reference see the following Screen Shot.

[image: Output Screen SHot using DataImport]

Now what my question is,
        How i need to get the Screen shot Solr DataImport result in the MVC Controller? How to accomplish this. Did anybody done this before? Need your Help...

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/oPW4Jq1PZYg/ETEXfRFQMJUJ